# How does GAS process the client_side variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is my test example.

The `count` variable is global variable.
It can runs successfully on the Javascript.

```js
var count = 1;

function test(){
  console.log(count)
  count += 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="test()">count plus button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The `count` variable is client variable,it plus one when click the button.

But when I use in GAS,there is result I do not expect.

I want to  Logger it,but `count` always equal "1",

it's same as we run the GAS-

everytime,and `count` be defined everytime,too.

[image]

I tried to use `PropertyService`,but property will let it to be global-

variable,all client will get same `count` variable.

And in the `CacheService`,cache will not exist more than 6 hours.

Can the GAS proccess the client variable as same as Javascript behavior,

or some basic concept I don't understand?

Thank you.

Comment: The function included in the HTML file is run in Javascript, on the browser--this is not Google Apps Script, which runs on the cloud. See [the Guide to Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) for an explanation of how to set up your project so that you can trigger Google Apps Script to run based on the Javascript in your browser.

Comment: write this as an answer, there is no better way to answer ;)